# Tapping from a recessed outlet box which is broken to a new surface-mounted box

Tags: electrical, receptacle

I have an outlet box made of cheap PVC material and now has broken screw holes. Although the wires in the box work fine, I can't install a new outlet into it. Moreover, the box is recessed in concrete so it's very difficult for me to replace the box itself.

To deal with this, I'm planning to install a surface-mounted box beside the recessed box so that I could still have an outlet in that location. I'm going to connect the wires from the recessed box to a wire in an external raceway ran to and connected to the new surface-mounted box.

Is there a code violation on what I'm planning to do? What are some best practices that I should keep in mind?

Comment: If it's just the screw holes that are causing the problem, I have some suggestions: 
1) Fill the screw holes with epoxy, once set, drill them out and re-tap with a 6/32 tap. 
2) without knowing the exact box, it might be possible to simply drill deeper into the box, restore the threads using the already mentioned 6/32 tap and longer screws. 
3) use slightly larger screws. You may have to enlarge the hole on the outlet, but that's not a big deal.   Just some thoughts, good luck.

Comment: If you'd post a photo, you'd save a whole lot of people a whole lot of guesswork too.

Answer (score 2):

Here we have an excellent example of the [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

In [this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/247727/how-to-cover-an-unused-outlet-box-with-worn-out-screw-holes) you asked about how to cover over a "worn out" junction box.

Now you're asking about running the wiring out of what I can only assume is the *same* box to a new, wall mount box next to it.

Next you'll probably ask about how to modify a box cover so you can have wire mold, conduit, or whatever come out of it.

Why not just take the answers from your first question and *repair* the box so you can reinstall an outlet in it and save yourself a ton of work?

- [This answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/247728/34147) suggested silicone, which may be OK for just a cover plate, but a comment suggested filling the holes with epoxy & making new ones for the mounting screws.
- [This answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/247729/34147) suggested using larger screws to work around the stripped holes in the existing box.

These answers were repeated in [George's comment on this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/247826/tapping-from-a-recessed-outlet-box-which-is-broken-to-a-new-surface-mounted-box#comment488639_247826).

See, you've got us repeating ourselves, wasting our time and yours, because you came up with a solution and asked about how to implement the various bits of the solution instead of presenting us with your original problem and asking for options on how to resolve it.

Comment: Thanks for the plug.   I agree with you, obviously.  + on your answer, please give me a + for my comment, care for all. ....George.